# Rails 3 - Incoming Mail Ingest via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I want to have a stable way to allow users to email posts to my app. I've been trying CloudMailin but need something more reliable and high performance / fast to respond.

Any Rails 3 - heroku solutions out there that can handle Incoming Email Ingest?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

[SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) is another option. [Here's the page](http://sendgrid.com/documentation/ApiParse) from the documentation about parsing incoming e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can only apologise if you have been having issues with CloudMailin. Perhaps we could try and rectify the issues you have been experiencing. Contact us via email and we can look into things. Emails should be arriving within milliseconds of sending. If they are not then there is something going on.